# Extracting a shape/polygon from a binary image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I'm trying to construct navigation meshes from mapping data.  One of the steps involves converting a binary image (where 0 represents occupied space and 1 represents free space) into a planar straight line graph.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this that is somewhat reliable.  My current thoughts are to use a Canny edge detector, and then run that through OpenCV's Hough line transform.  However, that has no guarantee that the lines detected are connected in a way representative of the original shape.

It is safe to assume that the map is relatively smooth, and that none of the regions touch one another.

EDIT - Here is an example image:

[image: sample map]

White regions represent free space

Black regions represent occupied space

Comment: Can you post some example images, and expected results? Also define a programming language and add it to the tags

Comment: you want to find possible pathes from A to B within the white areas? Afaik this is typically done by `A*` algorithm (from AI lecture several years ago). If you want to follow the visual version, try findContours followed by delauny triangulation / voronoi diagram to find the mid-points of the "pathes" (the medial axis)

Comment: The problem isn't figuring out how to find a valid path from A to B, it's getting the raster image into a format suitable for triangulation.  Your suggestion of findContours is definitely pointing me in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: if it is really just about getting the vertices defining the outer/inner borders of the white region, findContours should be exactly what you need. You can specify whether you want a dense representation or for example to only get vertices that are connected by straight lines between each other.

Comment: canny edges should work well, too I guess, but with findContours you already have some more information, so it might be more easy to work with findContours result than with canny edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edge detection is unnecessary/harmful on this binary image, just use [contour following](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html).

Then you turn the Freeman chains into polylines by the [Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) line simplification method.